# FB.getLoginStatus and Chrome Frame

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, authentication, frame, status

I am using the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=IE8">
```

to force IE8 users to make use of the Chrome rendering engine. However, this gives me problems with FB.getLoginStatus. The following does not give me the popup as intended:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { alert('test'); })
```

Moving the alert line above the function call does make it popup, so I guess the function is not executed. There are no problems with this piece of code in FF and Chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: Nobody knows? No support from Facebook here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120294/google-chrome-frame-and-facebook-javascript-sdk-cannot-login